# VB Script to run Excel Macro but plugin is not loading

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I've been trying to schedule a daily task to run a macro on an excel sheet of mine. The VB script calls the macro just fine. However, it does not wait for the plugin (it is the Reuters EIKON excel plugin) to load before running through the codes. Is there a method to wait for the plugins to load first?

```
strPath = "Desktop\datasave.xlsm" 
strMacro = "refresh" 

Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
objApp.Visible = True   

Set wbToRun = objApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath) 
objApp.Run strMacro
wbToRun.Save 
wbToRun.Close 
objApp.Quit
```

Comment: I think it should be handled in your `refresh` procedure. Mind sharing how it is structured?

Comment: Add-ins don't load when Excel is started programmatically: you will need to load it using your code.   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213489/add-ins-do-not-load-when-using-the-createobject-command-in-excel?spid=2512&sid=63

Comment: it basically creates a couple of '=RHistory()' formulas from a list of stock tickers and then runs 'Application.Run "EikonRefreshWorkbook"' @L42

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks. i'll try it out.